# Can there be two transition states (first order saddle point) connecting the same pair of minimas on a potential energy surface?

Tags: transition-state-theory

This is a purely hypothetical question. Consider a pair of local minimas A and B on a multi dimensional potential energy surface. Can there be two first saddle points (IE two different configurations) which would connect A and B ?
If the answer is yes, does this situation happen in a physical system ? Is there any example of a reaction proceeding in this format.

Comment: That sounds quite possible.

Comment: Yes. It sounds posible. But the situation between the two saddle points is an intermediate product.

Comment: I am asking about a situation where say you start an IRC scan from two transition states, they would connect the same pair of minimas.

Comment: By symmetry you could easily have this situation, but in general I would expect that one saddle point would be at a different height to the other and so not accessible.

Comment: @porphyrin Could you give an example (or a reference) of a reaction where you see this? In case you have come across a situation like this before before.

Comment: Sorry, no but I was thinking rather simply of something such as a metal complex, say, MX3  where there is 3 fold symmetry.